# sqlite3 C++ how sto assign SELECT data to a variable for later use?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm making a simple C++ application that is supposed to take some int ID's from sqlite3 database, store them in array for later use. From what I've read, I MUST  use the callback function in order to do so. The problem is, I don't know how to proceed after that.

This is the most common example of the sqlite3 callback function I keep finding:

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);

   for(i = 0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }

   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

What I would like to do, is to not simply print out the data but to return it into the main function and assign to a variable for later use.

Would appreciate if anyone provided an example of how to properly do so.

Comment: Callback? Huh? Use the [sqlite3_column_FOO()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) functions after `sqlite3_step()` on your prepared statements to get at the columns of the current row...

Comment: Thanks, thats much simplier that I anticipated.